# R-Package Building: How to Modify @source Line While Documenting Data to be Included in My R Package

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to include data in a package I am just building, I included the data object as follows:

```
set.seed(289805)
x <- room(10, mean = 0, var = 1)
```

I got assistance from [This Page](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) where I got a sample of code to modify. Here is the documentation jargon stored in the `\R` folder in `data.R` bellow:

```
#' Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds.
#'
#' A dataset containing the prices and other attributes of almost 54,000
#' diamonds.
#'
#' @format A data frame with 53940 rows and 10 variables:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{price}{price, in US dollars}
#'   \item{carat}{weight of the diamond, in carats}
#'   ...
#' }
#' @source \url{http://www.diamondse.info/}
"diamonds"
```

Since my data does not come from any web address I think I can not use `\url{}`. The data I am using is simulated data just like this:

```
set.seed(289805)
x <- room(10, mean = 0, var = 1)
```

**What I Want**

What will I use instead of `\url{}` in the   `#' @source \url{http://www.diamondse.info/}` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you have found a solution by now. I ran into the same problem.

I found that `@source` is [roxygen2](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/roxygen2.html) code that gets converted to [Rd documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-data-sets). Along the way I found [R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/writing-r-documentation-simplified/) description of the `\source` term for Rd documentation where they used "synthetic" to describe the source of their data.

So from what I can tell this is just a text field for describing where the data came from. The `\url` [markup](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Marking-text) just helps with formatting. In your case I would use something like:

```
#' @source Simulated data generated with the following code:
#'   set.seed(289805)
#'   x <- room(10, mean = 0, var = 1)
```